# HashMap is not rehashed as per the default values

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashtable

As per the Java docs

> An instance of HashMap has two parameters that affect its performance:
>   initial capacity and load factor. The capacity is the number of
>   buckets in the hash table, and the initial capacity is simply the
>   capacity at the time the hash table is created. The load factor is a
>   measure of how full the hash table is allowed to get before its
>   capacity is automatically increased. When the number of entries in the
>   hash table exceeds the product of the load factor and the current
>   capacity, the hash table is rehashed (that is, internal data
>   structures are rebuilt) so that the hash table has approximately twice
>   the number of buckets.

And

```
 the default initial capacity is 16 and the default load factor is 0.75.
```

As per the above, the threshold value for HashMap is `12(16 * 0.75)` and HashMap should be rehashed while putting 13th element.

I created an empty HashMap and put 16 elements in it. I ran it in debug mode. When 13th element was put I checked the debug variables and was surprised to see that threshhold value is still `12(as opposed to 24)` and table array still containing `16 entries(as opposed to 32)`. Only after 16th element is put, the hash table is rehashed making threshold value `24(32 * 0.75)`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you share some code and detail the debugging process and the java version ? This doesn't seem compatible with [the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.addEntry%28int%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cint%29)

Comment: @Anand Although I agree that this question should not be downvoted, I do not want to read such harsh comments. Please delete it. (And to egalize it, I upvoted.)

Comment: @Anand You might want to check out the behavior in Java 8. At least from a quick glance at the source code, the behavior should once again be consistent with the javadoc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer in the source code of `HashMap` (Java 7). Putting a value will run this code:

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    [...]
    modCount++;
    addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
    return null;
}
```

The interesting call is the method that adds an entry. Let's look into the source of this method:

```
void addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
    if ((size >= threshold) && (null != table[bucketIndex])) {
        resize(2 * table.length);
        hash = (null != key) ? hash(key) : 0;
        bucketIndex = indexFor(hash, table.length);
    }
    createEntry(hash, key, value, bucketIndex);
}
```

As we can see the resizing is only done if the size exceeds the threshold *and* the calculated bucket (for putting the entry) is not empty.

This behavior makes sense. As long as each entry goes into an empty bucket, a resize is not necessary, because each entry sits in the first place of the bucket's list and thus is easily found. *This is all about performance.* In fact, there are many implementation details that perform very well.

EDIT (as there is a difference between Java 6 and Java 7):

The above source code is from Java 7. Actually, in Java 6 the resizing behavior does only depend on the size and the threshold. This is the source of the `addEntry` method in Java 6:

```
void addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
Entry<K,V> e = table[bucketIndex];
    table[bucketIndex] = new Entry<K,V>(hash, key, value, e);
    if (size++ >= threshold)
        resize(2 * table.length);
}
```

That actually means that the `HashMap` implementation changed from Java 6 to Java 7 (due to performance reasons).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So,  the statement in Java doc "When the number of entries in the hash table exceeds the product of the load factor and the current capacity, the hash table is rehashed" is not correct right??

Comment: Indeed! It does not reflect the implementation anymore. It did in Java 6, though. A good example why we never should speak about implementation details in Javadoc. _Comments lie._

Comment: Interestingly, in Java 8 the resizing behavior appears to have been changed back to the Java 6 style of checking only size, likely due to the overall structure change of `HashMap` in Java 8